# iOS Memory usage increased from 40 to 140 when prepared for test flight

Tags: ios, memory, swift3, allocation, testflight

When i was developing my app, it had around 40 MB allocated. Some days ago I prepared everything for TestFlight. When I check the memory usage now it is around 140 mb. Is this behaviour normal? What kind of settings should I change?

Comment: Are you referring to the memory usage or the size of the app? Hot do you measure the memory usage?

Comment: no the size of the app is stable at 32mb. i refer to memory usage, which i measure via Xcode. I created a screenshot: http://imgur.com/PRJDhcZ

Comment: what does it mean, you prepared for `Testflight` ? Do you know how to profile your app for memory leaks?

Comment: Found out it had to do with an png image view.. strange.